# passing props through Route in react. sending a property from a child of component tree to other component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, react-router-dom

i have a simple react app in which there is complete tree of tutor components.TutorDashBoard is child of Tutors component working fine.
i want to send tutorId from TutorDashBoard component  to Courses component.
here is the simple codeSandBox to achieve this but tutorId not passed to Courses.
[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-greider-yhbwj?file=/src/Courses.jsx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of `Route` in `TutorDashBoard` and pass object to `to` props in `Link` component

```
<Link to={{
  pathname: '/Courses',
  state: {
    tutorId: tutorList[0].tutorId
  }
}}> MyCourses </Link>
```

Note:In the Courses component we should access `tutorId` as `const tutorId = props.location.state;` here is working codesandbox .[working codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-greider-yhbwj?file=/src/TutorDashBoard.jsx).

Comment: hi @JózefPodlecki i followed your suggestion but still same result does not send tutorId to courses component. here is [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-greider-yhbwj?file=/src/TutorDashBoard.jsx)